# terraform how to specify value of apigateway invoke_url using template file feature - locals or vars dont work

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-template-file

I have apigateway invoke_url that is unique and created by terraform, this unique url usually has form of

> https://123abc.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

That value has to go inside `index.html` for s3 object, I'm using template feature of terraform:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      SOME CODE    
        
          var backend_url = "${backend_api_gateway}/voting"              
    
      some code
          });
    
    </html>
```

Trying with 'locals' in tf did not work:

```
locals {
  backend_api_gateway = "${aws_apigatewayv2_stage.default.invoke_url}"
}
    
resource "aws_s3_object" "index_file_vote" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.frontend_vote.id
  key    = "index.html"
  content = templatefile("./vote/index.html.tpl", {
    backend_api_url = local.backend_api_gateway
  })
      
  depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket.frontend_vote, aws_apigatewayv2_api.main_apigateway] 
}
```

It gives error:

```
    Invalid function argument
    │
    │   on s3_bucket_vote.tf line 93, in resource "aws_s3_object" "index_file_vote":
    │   93:     content = templatefile("./vote/index.html.tpl", {
    │   94:         backend_api_url = local.backend_api_gateway
    │   95:     })
    │     ├────────────────
    │     │ local.backend_api_gateway will be known only after apply│
    │ Invalid value for "vars" parameter: vars map does not contain
    │ key "backend_api_gateway", referenced at
    │ ./vote/index.html.tpl:34,28-47.
```

Trying with vars, declaring future to be created apigateway's invoke url did not work:

```
variable "backend_api_gateway" {
  type = string
  default = "${aws_apigatewayv2_stage.default.invoke_url}" // error 'variables not allowed'
}
```

Comment: That is why I asked are all the files in the same module. If so, that is easy to fix.

Comment: there are no modules or separate folders - except for html, just bunch of tf files

Comment: So everything (including API Gateway) is in the same directory?

Comment: yes, apigateway.tf and sqs.tf and all other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are no modules involved, this should be easy to fix. First, the value assigned to the variable has to go away as it is not possible to use it that way. Second, you actually do not even need it. Third, you are using explicit dependencies, which is also not needed. Additionally, even though there is nothing wrong with using local variable, it is not needed. Here is the change required:

```
resource "aws_s3_object" "index_file_vote" {
    bucket = aws_s3_bucket.frontend_vote.id
    key    = "index.html"
    content = templatefile("./vote/index.html.tpl", {
        backend_api_url = aws_apigatewayv2_stage.default.invoke_url
    }) 
}
```

Comment: I fixed it like this:         backend_api_gateway = "${path.module}.apigateway_final_url"

Comment: i created output    apigateway_final_url" with 
output "apigateway_final_url" {
  value = replace(aws_apigatewayv2_stage.default.invoke_url, "wss://", "https://")
}

Comment: pretty much same, except i put it in separate output in apigateway.tf

Comment: sorry your solution worked! mine was producing "..apigateway_final_url"